# Writing floats to a binary file in C++ | Equivalent of Java's DataOutputStream.writeFloat()

Tags: java, c++, file-io, binary

I'm porting some code from Java to C++ and need to write floats to a binary file. In Java I use `DataOutputStream.writeFloat()`. How do I do it in C++?

I tried this method but it doesn't work:

```
std::ofstream out;
out.open(somePath, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

float f = 0.5;
out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&f), sizeof(float));
```

Comment: _"I tried this method but it doesn't work"_ - How about editing your post and describing exactly how it doesn't work.

Comment: The output from my Java code and C++ code are different

Comment: How are they different? **Please** _edit_ your post and include the information _there_!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java's default behaviour is to write files (and any other data streamed to IO) in [big endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). C++ writes files in native format. On a standard x86-derived PC native is little endian, so for 0.5 you get:

`0x00 00 00 3f` in C++

and

`0x3f 00 00 00` in Java.

In order to write files that can be read by both, you will have to establish which endian the output files will use and one of the programs will have to reverse their endian.

Answer (score 4):

Your code seems to work well!

main.cpp:

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
   std::ofstream out;
   out.open( "bin.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
   float f = 0.5;
   out.write( reinterpret_cast<const char*>( &f ), sizeof( float ));
   out.close();
   return 0;
}
```

Compiling, linking:

```
$ g++ -o m main.cpp
```

Executing:

```
m
```

Listing:

```
$ ls
bin.dat  m.exe  main.cpp
```

Editing bin.dat with Notepad++:

[image: Dump of bin.dat]

Comment: I'm writing to binary files, `<<` is for formatted output I believe